# Change CSS After x Characters

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a text string inside a `td`, as below:

```
<td>This is a long line</td>
```

What I want to be able to do is change the font size of all the characters after the first seven. Now I know I could do the following:

```
<td>This is<span class="different"> a long line</span></td>
```

Unfortunately I can't do that, as this is part of a table generated from a `php while` function, and the only way to target this is by using `CSS` `nth-child()` or similar, as it only occurs in one row. I do not think a `PHP` solution would work.

So how can I target this? I'm basically looking for something which would do the following:

```
#table2 td:nth-child(6) characters(n+7) { font-size: 8px; }
```

Also, if the above isn't possible, alternatively an option would be to apply a different `CSS` to the first seven characters, and apply the `nth-child` to the whole `td`, which will be overridden by the function to add `CSS` to the first seven.

CSS solution preferred, JS/jQuery welcome. If more information is needed, please comment and I will try and add.

Comment: The only way to do this is to wrap the text after the first seven characters in an element (like the span in your example). CSS has no way to count characters. You could use JS or PHP to handle the wrapping of the text in a separate, wrapping element.

Comment: @j08691 Could jQuery wrap them automatically though?

Comment: You can use jQuery to select the contents of the `<td>`, split the text after the seventh character, and wrap the second part in an element.

Comment: As others have stated, JS is your only hope here. Check out lettering.js http://letteringjs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pure CSS I'd say this is not possible. CSS works on elements and attributes, and text inside an element is neither of those.

But since you're also OK with jQuery, here goes:

```js
$("td").each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var part1 = text.substring(0, 7);
  var part2 = text.substring(7);
  $(this).html(part1 + "<i>" + part2 + "</i>");
})
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This is a long line</td>
    <td>Short</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>Supermagically long line</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Short explanation: get the text for every `td`, cut at position 7, and put it back in with extra added tags.

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery you can do something like this:

```js
var rep = $('div').text().substring(0,7);
$('div').html(function(i,html){
  return html.replace(rep, '<span>'+rep+'</span>');
})
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>This is a long line</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not `::nth-letter` selector, however [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/) provides us with a nice nth-everythin concept (which is more of a request to add to the standard).

There is an implementation here: https://github.com/FWeinb/nthEverything

And you can check this example:

```js
$(function() {
    $.fn.nthEverything();
});
```

```css
div::nth-letter(1),div::nth-letter(2),div::nth-letter(3),div::nth-letter(4),div::nth-letter(5),div::nth-letter(6),div::nth-letter(7) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/FWeinb/nthEverything/master/jquery.nthEverything.min.js"></script>
<div>asdf lkajsdflkjasdf</div>
```

> There is no implementation there for `n+X` so I had to duplicate the selectors